# Use contents of an array to print a String

Tags: java, arrays

I have written this code that takes the content of an integer array and converts it into a string of 4 letters based on if the number in the array is greater than, equal to, or less than 50. I'm worried about the length of the method and the redundancy though?

```
  public static String computePersonality(int[] percentB) {
     String personality = "";
     if (percentB[0] < 50) {
        personality += "E";
     } else if (percentB[0] > 50) {
        personality += "I";
     } else { 
        personality += "X";
     }   
     if (percentB[1] < 50) {
        personality += "S";
     } else if (percentB[1] > 50) {
        personality += "N";
     } else {
        personality += "X";
     }   
     if (percentB[2] < 50) {
        personality += "T";
     } else if (percentB[2] > 50) {
        personality += "F";
     } else {
        personality += "X";
     }
     if (percentB[3] < 50) {
        personality += "J";
     } else if (percentB[3] > 50) {
        personality += "P";
     } else {
        personality += "X";
     }
     System.out.println(personality);
     return personality;
  }
```

Comment: This might be more on topic on [CodeReview.se]

Comment: tell me this is all the code or you will have more lines (in this method)?Asking cause with full code i can make it better.

Comment: This question could be suitable for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help), as long as (a) your code works as intended, (b) your code is real code, rather than example code, and (c) your code is included in the body of the question. If you wish for a peer review to improve all aspects of your code, please post it on Code Review.

Answer (score 2):

You could extract your logic into a method that returns one of two chars based on the value of a single `int`. Something like,

```
private static char computeChar(int percent, char low, char high) {
    if (percent < 50) {
        return low;
    } else if (percent > 50) {
        return high;
    }
    return 'X';
}
```

Then your `computerPersonality` might be implemented with something like

```
public static String computePersonality(int[] percentB) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(4);
    sb.append(computeChar(percentB[0], 'E', 'I'));
    sb.append(computeChar(percentB[1], 'S', 'N'));
    sb.append(computeChar(percentB[2], 'T', 'F'));
    sb.append(computeChar(percentB[3], 'J', 'P'));
    System.out.println(sb);
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Snippet {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    computePersonality(new int[] { 5, 5, 50, 200 });
}

public static String computePersonality(int[] percentB) {
    String personality = "";
    String[] array = { "X","E", "I", "S", "N", "T", "F", "J", "P" };

   // Works when array.length-1=percentB.length*2;
    for (int value : percentB)
        personality += array[value == 50 ? 0 : (personality.length() * 2 + 1 + (value < 50 ? 0 : 1))];

    return personality;
}
}
```

> *Explanation of for:*

if(value==50) add "X"(array[0]) else add the letter from array in the position **personality.length*2**

+**1**(because i added X in the array at position 0 so i start from position 1)

+**0|1**(based on the logic of your algorithm.

You can add more letters in **array** on the same logic and it will work.